# How session is handled?

Tags: java, asp.net, session, redis, webserver

When user access a website for the first time, the `initial` server response may include a `SET-Cookie` header to set the session ID. Such as:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=04427E42C4AE7A5DD1CCE86B8B5F7110; Path=/TestSite/; HttpOnly
```

Then client will carry it in `cookie header` for subsequent HTTP requests: Such as:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=04427E42C4AE7A5DD1CCE86B8B5F7110
```

My question is:

1. So the real session object is some data structure created and maintained on server. Server just send its `index key` to client. When subsequent requests come, server will use that key to find session data store on server. And if necessary, server can use database to store the session data. **Is this mind picture correct?**
2. The following Java code is actually manipulating the session data which is stored `on server`. `Though` it looks like it is manipulating the request object. Right?

   `request.getSession().setAttribute("accountId", user.getId());`
3. The following code is essentially key (sessionid) looking up process. It looks for a session object `on server` by looking up for a `session id` cookie `sent from client`. Right?

   `Session s = (String) request.getSession();`
4. Is there any chance server doesn't send the `Set-Cookie` header? Or is it mandatory?
5. It seems some key-value store like `Redis` is very suitable for session store. Has anyone tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So the real session object is some data structure created and maintained on server.

With a servlet session, yes. But in general, you could also store "real data" in the session cookie itself. Has the downside that the user can see it and mess with it, and that it can only be quite small, but has the advantage that the server does not have to store the state (and share it with others in a cluster).

> The following Java code is actually manipulating the session data which is stored on server

That's right. The Servlet API provides for this interface through the `request`, because that way it is associated to the session key (and the individual user).

> Is there any chance server doesn't send the Set-Cookie header? Or is it mandatory?

You could turn that off. If you need sessions, but don't want cookies, it gets a bit complicated. You could attach a query parameter to every URL.

> It seems some key-value store like Redis is very suitable for session store. Has anyone tried that?

Yes, that's a common setup.

The default setup for servlet containers is to store the session in memory. This does not need any configuration or preparation, but works well only for single-server deployments. If you have more than one server, you need to either share the session information (using something like Redis), or have "sticky session" (configure the network to always send the same user to the same server).